# How can I make it shorter and better?

Tags: python, string, count, ord

I have an assignment about strings in loop and I need to find out how many (a,e,i,o,u) in the input .
I have done it but I think it's too long. I want to make it shorter but I have no idea how.

This is my code:

```
x=input("enter the taxt that you need me to count how many (a,e,i,o,u) in it:")

a=len(x)

x1=0

x2=0

x3=0

x4=0

x5=0

for i in range(a):
    h=ord(x[i])

    if h == 105:
        x1+=1
    elif h == 111: 
        x2+=1
    elif h == 97:
        x3+=1
    elif h == 117:
        x4+=1
    elif h == 101:
        x5+=1

print("There were",x3,"'a's")
print("There were",x5,"'e's")
print("There were",x1,"'i's")
print("There were",x2,"'o's")
print("There were",x4,"'u's")
```

Comment: Shall we _guess_ that this is… Python?

Comment: yes it is python , sorry did not mention that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count vowels and consonants in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43164161/how-to-count-vowels-and-consonants-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple approach according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155617/count-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string):

```
x = input("Enter the text that you need me to count how many (a,e,i,o,u) are in it:")

print("There were", x.count('a'), "'a's")
print("There were", x.count('e'), "'e's")
print("There were", x.count('i'), "'i's")
print("There were", x.count('o'), "'o's")
print("There were", x.count('u'), "'u's")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just define your list of characters you care about (vowels) in a string, then use [dictionary comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension-in-python). This code will print out what you want and also leave you with all of the values stored in a dictionary called `vowel_count`:

```
vowels = 'aeiou'

x=input("enter the taxt that you need me to count how many (a,e,i,o,u) in it:")

vowel_count = {vowel: x.count(vowel) for vowel in vowels}

for vowel in vowels:
    print("There were ",vowel_count[vowel]," '", vowel, " 's")
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `5` variables for counting and `5` constant for comparing use the dictionary:

```
h = {105: 0, 111: 0, 97: 0, 117: 0, 101: 0}
```

or - nicer -

```
h = {'i': 0, 'o': 0, 'a': 0, 'u': 0, 'e': 0}
```

so your full code will be

```
x = input("Enter the text that you need me to count how many (a,e,i,o,u) in it: ")
h = {'i': 0, 'o': 0, 'a': 0, 'u': 0, 'e': 0}

for i in x:              # there is no need to index characters in the string
    if i in h:
      h[i] += 1

for char in h: 
    print("There were {} '{}'s".format(h[char], char))
```