# How to get count of consonants

Tags: python

I have to get count of consonants present in given string
but seems like something missing. What do I need to modify to get the expected result?

**My code :**

```
var = 'aaeouAIyuiodffgXUEEE'
vowels='aeiou'
for i in vowels:
  if i is not var:
    print(var)
```

**Expected result:**

```
y 1
d 1
f 2
g 1
x 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count vowels and consonants in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43164161/how-to-count-vowels-and-consonants-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter` for this job. It's a `dict` subclass where each element is stored as dictionary keys and their counts are stored as dictionary values. So you can access the counts like:

```
>>> counts['y']
1
```

Then use `sorted` function on tuples of key-value pairs to sort the letters by alphabetical order and use `dict` constructor to re-construct the dictionary.

```
from collections import Counter
var = 'aaeouAIyuiodffgXUEEE'
vowels='aeiou'
counts = Counter([x for x in var.lower() if x not in vowels])
counts = dict(sorted(counts.items()))
```

Output:

```
{'d': 1, 'f': 2, 'g': 1, 'x': 1, 'y': 1}
```

You can find the sum of all consonants by:

```
total = sum(counts.values())
```

Output:

```
6
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an iterator `i` to navigate through the whole string `var`, character by character, and check for each character if it is a constant (or not).
Using a `vowels` string is very helpful, and you should check if at least one of the characters in it is equal to `i`. Python has already a function for that.

Something like that:

```
for i in var:
        if i not in vowels:
                # increase the consonant counter
```

How to increase the consonant counter? Well, you could use a dictionary that uses consonants as keys. For example:

```
cons = {'b': 0, 'c': 0, ...}
```

Don't forget to set all the values to 0 first. You could also create the dictionary using a `for` loop (if you want to do it faster and more efficient).

Now, whenever you find a consonant, just do `cons[i] = cons[i]+1`.
In the end, iterate through the dictionary and output every key, together with their values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve the same output without any module, we can use LIST to generate similar outcome.

```
    var = 'aaeouAIyuiodffgXUEEE'
    vowels='aeiou'
    
    l = []
    for i in var.lower():
        if i not in vowels:
            l.append(i)
    for i in sorted(set(l)):
        print(i, l.count(i))
```

**output:**

```
d 1
f 2
g 1
x 1
y 1
```

To know the total consonants, use "sum(l)"